# What Permissions Does MySQL Need for its Log Files?

Tags: linux, permissions, mysql

I’m trying to enable MySQL’s general log (at runtime, in case that matters) and set a path for the log file. These are the queries I issue after a connection to the server has been established:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log=1;
SET GLOBAL general_log_file='/home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server/mysql-log.log';
```

The server responds with:

```
code: 'EE_FILENOTFOUND',
errno: 29,
sqlMessage:
 'File \'/home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server/mysql-log.log\' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)',
sqlState: 'HY000',
index: 0,
sql: 'SET GLOBAL general_log=1;'
```

I can’t explain why MySQL can’t get permission to open the file, since it is owned by the user and group `mysql`, which has read and write permissions on it. The directories from `/` down to `ng-haushalt-server` (the parent of the log file) are all at least world-readable and world-executable:

```bsh
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root         4096 Jan 24 11:26 home/
drwxr-xr-x 72 bleistift2 bleistift2 196608 Feb 20 17:08 bleistift2/
drwxrwxr-x 22 bleistift2 bleistift2   4096 Feb 18 15:55 projekte/
drwxrwxr-x  7 bleistift2 bleistift2   4096 Feb 20 17:16 ng-haushalt-server/
-rw-rw-r--  1 mysql      mysql           0 Feb 20 17:30 mysql-log.log
```

I’ve also verified that the `mysql` user can write to the file by `cd`ing to it and writing in it manually:

```bsh
mysql@bleistift2-yoga / $ cd home
mysql@bleistift2-yoga /home $ cd bleistift2
mysql@bleistift2-yoga /home/bleistift2 $ cd projekte
mysql@bleistift2-yoga /home/bleistift2/projekte $ cd ng-haushalt-server/
mysql@bleistift2-yoga /home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server $ echo "works" >> mysql-log.log 
mysql@bleistift2-yoga /home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server $ cat mysql-log.log
works
```

I’ve tried providing the file with the above permissions and ownership, and I’ve tried without a pre-existing file, hoping MySQL would create it, but the error is the same in both cases.

I’ve tried the path with and without surrounding quotation marks.

I’ve asserted that there is no typo in the path by inspecting the default location for the general query log:

```
2020-02-21T11:39:13.191408Z     6 Query SET GLOBAL general_log=1
2020-02-21T11:39:13.194485Z     6 Query SET GLOBAL general_log_file="/home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server/mysql-log.log"
```

```
# Path copied from general log
$ stat /home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server/mysql-log.log
  File: '/home/bleistift2/projekte/ng-haushalt-server/mysql-log.log'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 10308h/66312d   Inode: 3039703     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  123/   mysql)   Gid: (  131/   mysql)
Access: 2020-02-21 12:38:14.717038315 +0100
Modify: 2020-02-20 17:30:20.639591019 +0100
Change: 2020-02-20 17:30:29.867590984 +0100
 Birth: -
```

I’ve seen [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208328/permission-denied-writing-to-mysql-log) where the answer suggests transferring ownership of the (default) containing directory to the `mysql` user. I would rather not do this, since the parent directory is the root development directory of a server-side application, and I don’t understand why it would be necessary if `mysql` can read and execute (cd into) it.

All other queries (`SELECT`, etc.) work.